# How can I query a ManyToMany relation table for a custom field

Tags: python, django

As can be seen in the code below, I have an intermediate model that defines a custom date field. How can I reference the date_assigned field in the relation model. I am trying find the number of tenders that were assigned to the "user" (i.e. CompanyProfile) on a particular date as per the date_assigned field in the relation model. The CompanyProfile (i.e. user) model and the Tender model share one thing in common, they both have a relationship with the Keywords model through a ManyToMany relationship. This is how I am able to find Tenders allocated to the CompanyProfile through the Keywords model.

This is the final result I am aiming for.

[image]

```
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    accountNumber = models.CharField(max_length=25, default=1, blank=False, null=False)
    companyName = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    companyRegNum = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    contactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    areaCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    deliveryEmails = models.TextField(blank=True)   #this is the list of all the people chosen to recieve daily notification.
    tenderCategory = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)    #links the user to the chosen category.
    provinces = models.ManyToManyField(Province, blank=False)    #links the user to the chosen Provinces.
    package = models.ForeignKey(Packages, default=1, blank=False)       #links the user to the chosen package.
    pymntMethod = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=3)   #this is the chosen payment method (e.g credit card=1, debit order=2 or direct debit=3)
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keywords)     #links the user to the chosen keywords.
    extraKeywords = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)  #this field acts as a container of extra keywords from the user. These are keywords that we do not have in our database.
    contractDuration = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=12)
    termsAndConditions = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=1)   #this is the T&C's field that must be agreed to by the client.
    commencementDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

    class Keywords(models.Model):
        keyword = models.CharField(max_length=150)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = ('Keywords')
            ordering = ['keyword', ]

        def __str__(self):
            return self.keyword


    #This is the model that stores the tender.
    class Tender(models.Model):
        tenderCategory = models.ManyToManyField(category, blank=False)       #this field holds the tender category, e.g. construction, engineering, human resources etc.
        tenderProvince = models.ForeignKey(Province, default=1, blank=False)       #this is the province the tender was advertised from.
        keywordTags = models.TextField(blank=False)      #this field holds keywords for the tender as per the tender title or as determined by the tender capturer.
        buyersName = models.CharField(max_length=100)   #this is the name of the Buyer e.g. Dept. of Transport, Transnet, Dept of Agriculture etc.
        summary = models.TextField(blank=False)      #this is the tender title as per the Buyer.
        refNum = models.CharField(max_length=100)    #tender ref number as per the Buyer.
        issueDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)     #date the tender was published
        closingDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)   #tender closing date
        siteInspection = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)     #site inspection date, if any
        enquiries = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) #this field stores details of the contact person, for the tender.
        description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)   #this is the body of the tender. the tender details are captured here.
        assigned_keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keywords, blank=True, through='tenderKeywords')
        matched = models.BooleanField(default=0, blank=False)
        capture_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=False, null=False)


    class TendersKeywords(models.Model):
        tender = models.ForeignKey(tender, related_name='tender_keywords')
        keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keywords, related_name='tender_keywords')
        date_assigned = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=False, null=False)
```

I am able to find the associated tenders for the CompanyProfile but I have a problem aggregating the results base on the tender issued_date which is defined in the relation model TendersKeywords.

Comment: It depends of the relation type you're trying to implement ? if many tender objects will have one and only tenderkeywords ? or every tender object will have one or many tenderkeyword ? or each tender object will have at max on tenderkeyword ? Define your needs first in order to answer to your question.

Comment: One tender object can be assigned to many keywords and one keyword can have many tenders assigned to it, hence to the M2M relationship.

Comment: If so, place the tenderkeyword class before the tender class. example: `assigned_keywords = models.ManyToManyField(tenderKeyword, through='keywords', related_name='tkeywords', blank=True)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am a bit confused by the way you changed the ManyToMany field above. I want to connect the tender objects to the "Keywords" objects through the "tenderKeyword" relation models. My only challenge is that when querying the "Keywords" objects from a "tender" object, I am struggling like to annotate the query by "date_assigned" field which is in the "tenderKeyword" model, as can be seen in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected result you show is a [model aggregation query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/). In particular, computing a count of matches grouped by a particular field, is a good use of [the `Count` aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count), applied to the queryset with [an `annotate` operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).

```python
import django.db

Tender.objects.values('issued').annotate(
    tenders=django.db.models.Count('issued'))
```

What that does:

- Use the Tender [model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#manager-names) (the `Tender.objects` attribute);
- Use [the `values` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) to make a queryset containing just the `issued` field value;
- [Annotate that queryset with a field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) named `tenders`, that:

  - Has the value computed by [the `Count` aggregate function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count) for each group.

That all assumes a coherent model schema; I had to make some guesses (your code as presented doesn't work, please review the guidelines on [creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In brief: Strip the example down to the minimum needed, and then actually run it to make sure it'll work for us too).

---

If you have an existing query and want to annotate that, then just apply the same technique:

```python
existing_queryset.values('tender_issued').annotate(
    tenders=django.db.models.Count('tender_issued'))
```

where `tender_issued` is whatever field in your queryset contains the value you want to group and count.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to modify your models

```
class tenderKeywords(models.Model):
    tender = models.ForeignKey(tender, related_name='tenderkeywords')
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keywords, related_name='tenderkeywords')
    date_assigned = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=False, null=False)
```

then:

```
count = tender.objects.filter(tenderKeywords__keyword__Keywords="", tenderKeywords__date_assigned= datetime)
```

Python developers have some standard in writing code. for example first letter of model's name should be capital. thanks for this.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but can you kindly explain what this line does. tenderKeywordes__keyword__Keywords=""

Comment: it filter all tender objects, that tenderKeywords property have a specific value. from tender model, you can access to tenderKeywords model and any property of it.